# How use all browser's width or why cannot use all browser's width

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using boostrap 3, asp mvc and I need use the full width of browser.

There is blank space at left and right.

Please see this image: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlLZaH7Z2YlNgqkBq_uE_RHB5G1Yjw

How can use all screen's width

Thanks a lot!.

This is the html code (cshtml), I not sure if there is more that I must provide to understand the problem. Please feel free to ask for more details.

```
@model IEnumerable<PftWeb.Models.Cargo>
@using PftWeb.Models

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Listado de Cargos";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Listado de cargos
    </div>

    <table id="TableList" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>

                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Descripcion)

                </th>

                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descripcion)
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Cargos", new { id = item.CargoId }))
                        {
                            @Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Edit", new { id = item.CargoId }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-xs" })
                            @Html.ActionLink("Eliminar", "Delete", new { id = item.CargoId }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-xs" })
                        }

                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
@Html.ActionLink("Crear nuevo Cargo", "Create", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })

<script>
    var datatable;
    $(document).ready(function () {

        dataTable = $('#TableList').removeAttr('width').DataTable(
      {
          "language": {
              "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
              "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
              "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
              "sEmptyTable": "No hay elementos aun...",
              "sInfo": "",
              "sInfoEmpty": "",
              "sInfoFiltered": "",
              "sInfoPostFix": "",
              "sSearch": "Buscar:",
              "sUrl": "",
              "sInfoThousands": ",",
              "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
              "oPaginate": {
                  "sFirst": "Primero",
                  "sLast": "Último",
                  "sNext": "Siguiente",
                  "sPrevious": "Anterior"
              },
              "oAria": {
                  "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                  "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
              }
          },
          "autoWidth": true,
          paging: true,
          searching: true,
          "ordering": true,
          "order": [[0, "asc"]],
          columns: [

              {

                  orderable: true,
                  searchable: true
              },

               {
                   orderable: false, searchable: false
               }
          ]

      });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that you're using the default mvc project scaffold. If that's the case, in the `_layout` view there is a `div` with class `container` that wraps `@RenderBody()`... removing the `class="container"` would solve the issue if this is the case as the `container` class sets margins on the page

Comment: Thanks! @GregH this solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `_layout` view that is wrapping your other views, you'll see a `div` with class `container` that wraps the call to `RenderBody()`. The class `container` is adding margins to the view that you are rendering by default.

If you remove the class `container` from the wrapping div, then these margins will go away.

Answer (score 0):

With BS 3 you would generally place you content within a Container, Row then Column (CRC).

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid

This sets the margin left/right to the correct values.
Try placing your table within a row and then a column. Something like:

```
<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12">Your table</div></div>
```

Comment: Thank Alex, but this not solve the problem.@GregH comment solved the issue.